# Unable to upload images while publishing my Android App

Tags: android, google-play

while publishing an app in android market , Google want two screen shots of a particular dimension and a high res. icon. I did what they said with exact dimensions they require.

Here, I have a problem .. I'm unable to upload screenshots and icon image while publishing my application in android Market. I receives an error something like browser extension and json etc .. Anyone please help
The error is something like this 
**Unable to parse response. If you have a browser extension or add-on installed which changes the JSON response, please disable and refresh this page.**

Comment: while publishing an app in android market , Google want two screen shots of a particular dimension and a high res. icon. I did what they said with exact dimensions they require but when I try to upload them it gives me this error ...

Comment: Got exact the same error, you figured it out already?

Comment: Me too, any of you guys fixed it? I've tried both Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I got the above error, then I tried it with the dreaded IE and it worked :/